# Check if string contains consecutive repeated substring

Tags: string, algorithm

I got an interview problem which asks to determine whether or not a given string contains substring repeated right after it. For example:

ATAYTAYUV contains TAY after TAY
AABCD contains A after A
ABCAB contains two AB, but they are not consecutive, so the answer is negative

My idea was to look at the first letter, find its second occurrence then check letter by letter if the letters after the first occurrence match the letters after the second occurrence. If they all do, the answer is positive. If not, once I get a mismatch, I can repeat the process but starting with the last letter I checked, since I would not be able to get a repeated sequence up to that point.

I am not sure if the approach is correct or if it is the mos efficient.

Comment: The approach you describe definitely sounds correct.

Comment: The approach your mentioned wouldn't work with this testcase.

ABACABAC.

Here you would first compare AB with AC and since it is a mismatch, you'll move starting pointer to index 3(A). Now trying to match AC(index 3,4) with AB(index 5,6) and its a mismatch again. Eventually this would return false but the answer is true since ABAC ABAC can be considered as two consecutive repeated substring.

Comment: I would do a minor modification here to make the algorithm correct.

If you find a mismatch, don't reset the start position. Let it be the original starting point and keep repeating the process for all next occurrences of the original letter.

The complexity would be O(n^2) since you would be traversing the whole string once for every letter in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are looking for a repeating pattern of length 3. If you write the string shifted right by three positions in front of itself (and trimmed), you can detect runs of 3 identical characters.

```
ATAYTAYUV 
   ATAYTA
```

Repeat this for all lengths up to N/2.